# How to change the ROOT application?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6

I'm trying to change the default application of a Tomcat 6 webserver to a different application than "ROOT" (inside webapps folder). What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 134):

There are three methods:

- First shutdown your Tomcat from the its `bin` directory (`sh shutdown.sh`). Then delete all the content of your Tomcat `webapps` folder (`rm -fr *`). Then rename your WAR file to `ROOT.war`, and finally start your Tomcat from the `bin` directory (`sh startup.sh`).
- Leave your war file in `$CATALINA_BASE/webapps` under its original name. Turn off 
  **autoDeploy** and **deployOnStartup** in your Host element in the `server.xml` file.
  Explicitly define all application Contexts in `server.xml`, specifying both the **path** 
  and **docBase** attributes. You must do this because you have disabled all the Tomcat 
  auto-deploy mechanisms, and Tomcat will not deploy your applications anymore
  unless it finds their Context in the `server.xml`.

  > second method: in order to make any change to any
  >   application, you will have to stop and restart Tomcat.
- Place your WAR file outside of `$CATALINA_BASE/webapps` (it must be outside 
  to prevent double deployment). Place a context file named `ROOT.xml` in `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/`. The single element in this context file MUST have a 
  **docBase** attribute pointing to the location of your WAR file. The path element 
  should not be set - it is derived from the name of the `.xml` file, in this 
  case `ROOT.xml`. See the [documentation for the Context container](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html) for details.

[Reference](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo#How_do_I_make_my_web_application_be_the_Tomcat_default_application_.3F)

Comment: I tried the first method and it works! Bdw - you DON'T need to delete everything. I just deleted the ROOT folder and renamed my war to ROOT.war and it works like a charm.

Comment: I know its not really following the sof rules but screw it..... Thanks! I wish I could upvote more than once. Super helpful. BTW, i _had_ to restart tomcat before this would work, @hostnik.

Comment: @danny-london's third method didn't work for me in Tomcat 7, but it does work if you place the ROOT.xml file in the `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]` directory (which for my rather basic setup is `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost`). Refer to [the Context Container documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context).

Comment: Modern alternative to starting Tomcat: `sudo systemctl start tomcatx` where `x` stands for the version number

Answer (score 26):

Adding a `<Context>` tag in the `<Host>` tag in `server.xml` for Tomcat 6 will resolve the problem.

If you use `path=""` empty you can use a URL like `http://localhost/first.do`.

In the context tag set attributes `docBase="E:\struts-ITRCbook\myStrutsbook"` and `reloadable="true"`, then end the context tag.

It should look something like this:

```xml
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" 
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
        xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
    <Context path="" docBase="E:\struts-ITRCbook\myStrutsbook" reloadable="true">
    </Context>
</Host>
```

Comment: is this also true for tomcat 7?

Comment: Per the documentation: For Tomcat 6, unlike Tomcat 4.x, it is NOT recommended to place <Context> elements directly in the server.xml file. This is because it makes modifying the Context configuration more invasive since the main conf/server.xml file cannot be reloaded without restarting Tomcat.

Comment: let notify this approach has side effect! myStrutsbook will deploy twice Once for localhost:8080 and once for localhost:8080/myStrutsbook ! and may cause database connection errors and more resource usage

Answer (score 26):

In Tomcat 7 with these changes, i'm able to access `myAPP` at `/` and `ROOT` at `/ROOT`

```
<Context path="" docBase="myAPP"/>
<Context path="ROOT" docBase="ROOT"/>
```

Add above to the `<Host>` section in server.xml

Comment: Just the solution I was looking for! Thanks a million, Sudheer! Works like a charm for me. And hey! I have another question. When I do access the ROOT by `/ROOT` and try logging into the Manager page using the correct credentials, I'm denied access. Would you know how to fix this?

Comment: @Sudheer Palyam I did the same. I changed the server.xml file, and then I started the server. But when I loaded/visited the localhost:8080, it showed me 404 status error. If I delete these lines from server.xml, then It load the above port.

Answer (score 17):

ROOT default app is usually Tomcat Manager - which can be useful so I felt like keeping it around.

So the way i made ***my*** app ROOT and kept TCmgr was like this.

renamed ROOT to something else

```
mv ROOT TCmgr
```

then created a symbolic link  whereby ROOT points to the app i want to make the default.

```
ln -s <your app> ROOT
```

worked for me and seemed the easiest approach.

Comment: @Vic you are right, but windows does have symbolic links, in XP and above I think you can use mklink.  Please note I have not done this and there my be other reasons not to use symbolic links.

Answer (score 14):

You can do this in a slightly hack-y way by:

1. Stop Tomcat
2. Move ROOT.war aside and rm -rf webapps/ROOT
3. Copy the webapp you want to webapps/ROOT.war
4. Start Tomcat

Comment: Ugly or maybe icky, but hacky might be the wrong term since that appears to be the official/supported method.

Answer (score 13):

According to the Apache Tomcat docs, you can change the application by creating a ROOT.xml file.  See this for more info:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html

"The default web application may be defined by using a file called ROOT.xml."

Answer (score 3):

An alternative solution would be to create a servlet that sends a redirect to the desired default webapp and map that servlet to all urls in the ROOT webapp.

```
package com.example.servlet;

import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class RedirectServlet extends HttpServlet {

  @Override
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.sendRedirect("/myRootWebapp");
  }
}
```

Add the above class to 
`CATALINA_BASE/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/com/example/servlet`. 
And add the following to 
`CATALINA_BASE/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/web.xml`:

```
  <servlet>
    <display-name>Redirect</display-name>
    <servlet-name>Redirect</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.servlet.RedirectServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Redirect</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

And if desired you could easily modify the RedirectServlet to accept an init param to allow you to set the default webapp without having to modify the source.

I'm not sure if doing this would have any negative implications, but I did test this and it does seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

the context.xml configuration didn't work for me. Tomcat 6.0.29 complains about the docBase being inside the appBase: ... 
For Tomcat 5 this did actually work.

So one solution is to put the application in the ROOT folder.

Another very simple solution is to put an index.jsp to ROOT that redirects to my application like this: 
response.sendRedirect("/MyApplicationXy");

Best Regards,
Jan

Answer (score 1):

I've got a problem when configured Tomcat' `server.xml` and added Context element.
He just doesn't want to use my config:
http://www.oreillynet.com/onjava/blog/2006/12/configuration_antipatterns_tom.html

If you're in a `Unix-like` system:

1. `mv $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/ROOT $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/___ROOT`
2. `ln -s $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/your_project $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/ROOT`

Done.

Works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimate way to change tomcat root application. Tested on Tomcat 7 and 8.

1. Move to the tomcat webapps directory:

   Example on my machine: `~/stack/apache-tomcat/webapps`
2. Rename, replace or delete ROOT folder. My advice is renaming or create a copy for backup.
   Example rename ROOT to RENAMED_ROOT:

   `mv ROOT RENAMED_ROOT`
3. Move war file with your application to tomcat webapps directory
   (its a directory where was old ROOT folder, on my machine: ~/stack/apache-tomcat/webapps)

> War file must have a name **ROOT.war**. Rename your aplication if it's
>   need: **yourApplicationName.war -> ROOT.war**

4. Restart tomcat.
   After restart your application will be a root.

Answer (score 0):

I'll look at my docs; there's a way of specifying a  configuration to change the path of the root web application away from ROOT (or ROOT.war), but it seems to have changed between Tomcat 5 and 6.

Found this:

http://www.nabble.com/Re:-Tomcat-6-and-ROOT-application...-td20017401.html

So, it seems that changing the root path (in ROOT.xml) is possible, but a bit broken -- you need to move your WAR outside of the auto-deployment directory.  Mind if I ask why just renaming your file to ROOT.war isn't a workable solution?

Comment: Unfortunately changing the war file to ROOT.war is not an option for me.

Jacques

Comment: a bit late, but... for me i can't change it because i am using a system created by a third party, who seems to have hard coded some locations to jar files.... so moving it to ROOT.war makes a problem, since the original application looks for its own jar under a directory which is in [originalapp.war]

Answer (score 0):

Not a very good solution but one way is to redirect from the ROOT app to YourWebApp. For this you need to modify the ROOT index.html.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Redirecting to /YourWebApp</title>
    </head>
    <body onLoad="javascript:window.location='YourWebApp';">
    </body>
</html>
```

OR

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Redirecting to /YourWebApp</title>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=YourWebApp" />
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Reference : http://staraphd.blogspot.com/2009/10/change-default-root-folder-in-tomcat.html

Answer (score -4):

In Tomcat 7 (under Windows server) I didn't add or edit anything to any configuration file. I just renamed the ROOT folder to something else and renamed my application folder to ROOT and it worked fine.

Comment: This might be a good workaround, but Jaques' question is about how to change the default application; there may be reasons why he cannot change the contents of the ROOT folder.