# how to remove the war and project name on a grails project

Tags: tomcat, grails

I have a grails app I want to host.  The issue is I'm not sure how to map my domain name to my project.  On my machine the url is

```
localhost:8080/myProject/controller/action
```

it is my understanding that when I purchase a domain, it will replace the "ENDPOINT" in my url, making

```
www.mydomain.com/myProject/controller/action
```

What do I need to do when I purchase my domain so that the website is

```
www.mydomain.com/controller/action
```

and have the domain name cover

```
localhost:8080/myProject
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add A-record, that points to your host's IP address, in the NameServer.
When you purchase the domain, the registrar will let you configure this on their NameServer.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options.  Use a web server to proxy the app server, and have it replace the project name.  The other option if you are using tomcat is to replace the ROOT.war and have tomcat listen to 443 and 80.

In my production environments I use nginx to proxy tomcat, and also have nginx serve the artifacts such as javascript.

[Deploying my application at the root in Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328518/deploying-my-application-in-tomcat-in-the-root) talks about ROOT.war

Here is a link to using nginx

http://www.componentix.com/blog/18/hosting-grails-web-applications-using-tomcat-and-nginx-our-configuration

I prefer nginx ... but it adds a layer of complexity.

You will also need to update grails.serverURL in Config.groovy.