# Short url for java web application

Tags: java, tomcat

I have an application that can be browsed into when i go to `http://localhost:8080/application name/app/index.html#/home`

I would like to be able to browse it when i just hit the server name e.g `http://localhost:8080`

How can it be done ?

Comment: That depends a lot on which web server is hosting your app.

Comment: call your app ROOT and copy it in the webapps

Comment: Or create a good old bookmark...

Comment: I am using a tomcat server

Comment: If i will call it ROOT i will still see the the app in the url http://localhost:8080/app/index.html#/home

Comment: If you are developing a single page app (guessed it from #/home) all you can do is url rewriting. As already mentioned deploying your app into the ROOT folder will remove the /appname/ part.

Answer (score 1):

When using tomcat, in web.xml you can add :

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>app/index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Then you can access it with :

```
http://localhost:8080/application_name/
```

This will only shorter the root page of your application, but I think this is the more important when you want to spread it.

After doing this you should take a look at :

[Deploying my application at the root in Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328518/deploying-my-application-in-tomcat-in-the-root)

Comment: Thanks for the reply,i tried but <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>app/index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list> didnt work