# How to set context path to root("/") in Tomcat 7.0 when using Maven

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, maven-plugin

I hava a maven project, pom.xml contains tomcat plugin.

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
 <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>2.2</version>
</plugin>
```

I've downloaded Tomcat 7, so I've got Tomcat directory (apache-tomcat-7.0.56). I tried three goals to run my project:

`tomcat7:run, tomcat7:run-war, tomcat7:run-war-only`

My application is running at `http://localhost:8080/projectname`, if I run tomcat7:run-war,   `projectname-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war` appears in the /target directory of my project.

I want to run my application at `http://localhost:8080/`.

I know this question was asked before, but unfortunately those solutions didn't help me.

I tried both methods from the first answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328518/deploying-my-application-in-tomcat-in-the-root/%22this%22).

First method didn't work for me, after renaming war nothing changed, tomcat7:run-war-only requires war with name like projectname-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war.

The second method changed nothing (I tried both

`<Context path="" docBase="projectname-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT" debug="0" reloadable="true"></Context>`
and

```
<Context path="" docBase="projectname" debug="0" reloadable="true"></Context>)
```

I have also looked throw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276989/howto-set-the-context-path-of-a-web-application-in-tomcat-7-0), but I don't have `<catalina_home>/conf/Catalina/localhost/` directory in my Tomcat directory.

Comment: Take a look at the settings of this plugin.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Have you tried changing the context path by setting it in the configuration section of the Maven plugin?

FYI: Find the current version of the plugin [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin.html)

```
  <plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
   <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.2</version>

    <configuration>
      <path>/</path>
    </configuration>

  </plugin>
```

Comment: Can you please let me know where <path>/</path> needs to be specified under  which plugin?

Comment: @Srinivas           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration><path>/</path></configuration>
                <version>2.2</version>
            </plugin>

Comment: The documentation states explicitly *not* to use `/`for the path: http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.1/tomcat7-maven-plugin/standalone-war-mojo.html

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't state why, and it works very well.

Comment: Here is question for the "why" part.
https://stackoverflow.com/q/55247848/1433665

Answer (score 0):

I am using tomee and it works for me.

Add the context tag to the pom file as follows:-

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
 <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>2.2</version>
 <configuration>
   ..
   <context>ROOT<context>
   ..
 </configuration>
</plugin>
```