# Spring + Tomcat multi tenancy based on Request URL

Tags: spring, apache, spring-mvc, tomcat, multi-tenant

We have a single application which is used by multiple customers. It's every time the same app, but with a different database.

Our current setup consists of:

- Apache 2 Web Server
- Tomcat 8
- Spring 4.1

The Web Server routes specific URLs to Tomcat, i.e.

- /customer1 -> tomcat/customer1
- /customer2 -> tomcat/customer2

Now we'd like to keep those entries within Apache Config, but somehow configure Tomcat and Spring. Basically Tomcat should take every request (maybe defined by regex - not necessary) and route it to one application.

Currently one application runs at `/webapps/customer1` and another instance at `/webapps/customer2`.

In the future the application should somehow run at `/webapps/*`, so within spring I can have a look at the request URL and choose `db_customer1` for requests at `/customer1/...` and the same for `customer2`.

Is this possible to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want single application that uses 2 (or more) databases, depending on the customer. Customer is determined via URL.

If that is the case, you should take a look at `AbstractRoutingDatasource` and create your own implementation of that class. It allows you to use different datasources in a single application. You should then create a Filter or maybe Interceptor that would intercept the URL and then, based on the URL, route the routing datasource to the appropriate underlying datasource.

Take a look at this example linked below: it has a customer routing datasource that uses different database for different logged in user:
https://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/

Comment: Thank you. That's helpful in terms of Spring. But: How to get the app running on Tomcat, so that multiple Routes point to the application? By default Tomcat routes `customer1.war` to `/customer1` and `customer2.war` to `/customer2`. But I need `myApp.war` to `/customer1` and `/customer2` (Or maybe `/*`).

Comment: For that I would suggest deploying the app as tomcat's root. Then all requests will go to the app and you can manage `/customer1` and  `/customer2` at app level. For this config take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328518/deploying-my-application-at-the-root-in-tomcat . Otherwise, you could setup reverse proxy (for example in Apache) to map those URLs to tomcat (which I believe you're already doing).