# I have tomcat7 server i want that we access .war

Tags: java, url, tomcat7

I have **tomcat7** server in it I have upload `.war file` in webapps directory. After that we access it url **"localhost:8080/warfile"**

But here I want that we access `.war` in this url **"localhost:8080"**  is it possible, if yes then please help me

thanks

Comment: I think you can do this by using URL re-writting. But in that case, you lose the page which displayed when you hit localhost:8080

Comment: it means redirection Mr. Mo.ashfaq

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deploying my application at the root in Tomcat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328518/deploying-my-application-at-the-root-in-tomcat)

Answer (score -1):

Rename your war file to ROOT.war, to access it via yourhost.com rather than yourhost.com/nameOfWar.

Also, especially in a local environment, set the path variable to "/" in your  server.xml. In eclipse, you will probably have a "Servers" project folder, where you can simply edit the server.xml of the specific tomcat server.

```
<Context docBase="YourApp" path="/" reloadable="true"
                    source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:YourApp" />
```

Comment: Thanks sir for valuable reply

Comment: But,  what is url of it after do this

Comment: If it works, please mark it as solved and upvote. In a local environment, the url will be localhost:8080/ rather than localhost:8080/yourapp.

Comment: "If it works, please mark it as solved and upvote. In a local environment, the url will be localhost:8080/ rather than localhost:8080/yourapp "                                                                                                                                  here if i want open my .war file in url "localhost:8080/myapp" instead of "localhost:8080" then what i can do for this

Comment: Did you even try what I wrote? Edit the path attribute in your server.xml.