# Remove port in apache tomcat 7 (linux Centos)

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, jsp

I have installed apache on centos and configured cpanel/whm.
I have a jsp project which is hosted on the server and also we need to maintain some php files for supporting helpdesk.

jsp project url is http:www.xyz.in:8090/jspproject/index.jsp

php files url is http:www.xyz.in/heldesk/index.html

helpdesk folder and jspproject are placed under public_html i.e. /home/account/publich_html.

The following task is required

1. When user types url either "http:www.xyz.in" or "http:www.xyz.in:8090" then jspproject should run (http:www.xyz.in/jspproject/index.jsp) and still url must be "http:www.xyz.in/jspproject"
2. When user types url as "http:www.xyz.in/helpdesk" then helpdesk (php files) should run (http:www.xyn.in/helpdesk/index.html) and url must be "http:www.xyn.in/helpdesk"

.htaccess is placed under /home/account/public_html/

Please advice me how to handle in .htaccess with rewrite rule.

Comment: Tomcat does not use .htaccess, that is an http apache server tool.

Comment: can you please let me know how to achieve above task

Comment: I suggest having a look at what I wrote here as that will take care of some of your issues like port numbers and subdirectories. I have not yet needed to have a default forward to a subdirectory, and someone else needs to help you there, although I would suggest to run the main page in the root and the helpdesk in the subdirectory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328518/deploying-my-application-at-the-root-in-tomcat/33248281#33248281