# POint domain to ec2 ip with page name

Tags: html, tomcat, amazon-ec2, dns

I have a domain in bigrock and Ihave ec2 instance running on aws with elastic ip.
Over there I have instantiated tomcat server and it has my website files in its htdocs folder.
I have managed DNS of bigrock to this ec2 ip.
So when I browse for my domain name in browser it launches tomcat home home page insteade of index.html file

So how can I load index.html file by default?

Comment: The fact that you are accessing your tomcat home page means your AWS configuration is ok, in order to understand what goes on in your server some more info is required. Could you upload your tomcat configuration file? and the address you browse to?

Comment: default config is there. And when I open my site it open the tomcat server home page. And when I add /site to domain then It opens my site. So how can I load /mysite default with ip

Answer (score 0):

You can't point a domain name to a specific web page. A domain name points to a server. You have already configured your domain name correctly.

You have a few options:

1. Configure Tomcat to [serve your application as the root context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328518/deploying-my-application-at-the-root-in-tomcat).
2. Place a reverse proxy like [Nginx in front of Tomcat](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/javaservers/), and configure it to route requests to your Tomcat app.