# Tomcat: Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

**Problem:** Running my project on a `tomcat` I get the following issue:

```
SCHWERWIEGEND: Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.releaseCaches(NioEndpoint.java:316)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:492)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.destroy(AbstractEndpoint.java:821)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy(AbstractProtocol.java:534)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.destroyInternal(Connector.java:1023)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:589)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
```

**Question:** Is the problem caused by my web.xml file?

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>SMS Cloud Service</display-name>


</web-app>
```

HomeController.java

```
  @RestController
    public class HomeController {

        private final MachineRepository machineRepository;

        @Autowired
        HomeController(MachineRepository machineRepository) {
            this.machineRepository = machineRepository;
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/maschine/getAll", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        Iterable<Machine> readMachines(@PathVariable String userId) {

            return this.machineRepository.findAll();
        }
    }
```

**Note:** I am running the project on

> Spring Tool Suite
>
> Version: 3.7.3.RELEASE Build Id: 201602251025 Platform: Eclipse Neon
>   (4.6)

Tomcat's server.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
     define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
     Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
 -->
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
  <Service name="Catalina">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->


    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->
    <!-- Define a SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the NIO implementation that requires the JSSE
         style configuration. When using the APR/native implementation, the
         OpenSSL style configuration is required as described in the APR/native
         documentation -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
    -->

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />


    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
    -->
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->

      <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

Comment: What is in your tomcat server.xml? Port configurations are done in that. Also, are you running your project in an IDE based Server environment?

Comment: For server.xml please see my updated post. I am running my tomcat inside my Spring Tool Suite. Version: 3.7.3.RELEASE
Build Id: 201602251025
Platform: Eclipse Neon (4.6) - Is that the correct answer to your question?

Comment: I have got this error when running inside an IDE environment. The WTP environment modifies the Tomcat environment in its own terms and cannot guarantee a successful/graceful run all the time. Can you try running your application in a standalone tomcat server as well please?

Comment: I get the same output for running the project on a xampp tomcat server

Comment: How have you configured your DispatcherServlet? Are there any configuration/code which manipulates your response? Unable to replicate this mate.

Comment: Probably not this case, but I had exactly the same error when made ROOT.war application as the root of Tomcat as described there (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328518/deploying-my-application-at-the-root-in-tomcat) but afterward removed ROOT.war by an accident. Placing ROOT back resolved it.

Comment: @jublikon Hi Jublikon , can you please share complete error log trace which you encountered while running your application ?

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a similar problem when I publish a Maven web project after cleaning it in **Eclipse**.
In my experience, to sovle this problem, you should:

1. update the Maven project
2. config build path --> remove unnecessary source folders
3. [make sure web deployment assembly looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EjT5.png),remove unnecessary entries
4. run configurations --> choose Tomcat --> then check Classpath, [make sure it looks like it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m97sc.png)
5. At last, do not forget to build project.

Works for me. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Try to look for previous error messages in the log.

In my case for instance there was an error in servlets definition in web.xml.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem debugging a Web Application under Eclipse.
I had to open every project of web applications deployed on Server Tomcat, and then problem was solved

Answer (score 0):

To see the directory where saving the jar package download by Maven and delete all child directory, then back to eclipse and click update the Maven project.
This is my experience and I succeed by this way.

Comment: how does this answer OP's question?

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing work on the JSP Servlet web application then this issue is caused due to not proper servlet configuration in the `web.xml`.

It should be proper as follow example

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>SimpleServletProject</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>XmlServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.yogi.XmlServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>XmlServlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/xmlservlet</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Spring application development I have faced the above problem.

Solution: in the `pom.xml` file, I added `slf4j` as a dependency and the problem was resolved.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.12</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue usually occurs when something is wrong in web.xml.
Check if all class mapping is correctly present. 
Example: If filter-mapping is declared, then appropriate filter for the same name should also be declared.

In the case of Spring, check if WebApplicationInitializer is properly defined.

Answer (score 0):

In my case for instance there was an error in servlets definition in web.xml.
then I edited web.xml file and solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue,
i. in eclipse right click on the project
ii. select maven option
iii. Click on the Update Project
once the project updated my issue got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I got same issue due to wrong url-pattern

```
<url-pattern>*/*</url-pattern>
```

right :

```
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
```

Answer (score -2):

Maven update for the project did the trick for me.