# How to specify root url tomcat?

Tags: java, xml, tomcat

for example app.war. I want to change root url for ruuning program on it.

I am absolutely confused. I tried out to specify root url in context.xml(in my app folder, and I've tried to add ROOT.xml. But it doesn't work(in general, I don't know where I make mistake of changing parametrs, I've looked over all tips. If i change in `/web-inf` `context.xml`, then tomcat removes all changing. Tomcat doesn't see `ROOT.xml` in specific folder. Please, may be someone can write more explicitly these steps and explain some things, which happened with me preventing my Tomcat from working correctly.

this is `C:\Users\user\Desktop\psc\ProductCatalog\psc-ui\target\tomcat\conf\context.xml` below

```
<Context>

<!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
<WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>

<!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
<!--
<Manager pathname="" />
-->

<!-- Uncomment this to enable Comet connection tacking (provides events
     on session expiration as well as webapp lifecycle) -->
<!--
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.CometConnectionManagerValve" />
-->

<Environment name="SQL.log" value="DEBUG" type="java.lang.String"/>
```

this is `C:\Users\Alexander.Luchko\Desktop\psc\ProductCatalog\psc-ui\target\ProductCatalog\META-INF\context.xml` below

```
<Context>
<Parameter name="javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE" value="Production" override="false"/>
```

........

```
<Resource ....
```

sorry for my bad english! in advance

Comment: You mean this ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/5328636/1536382

Comment: thanks any way, but it create three copies programm on root, on name programm and my root. It is strange behaviour and i think don't use server.xml for this task, i would like to have explicit declaration for my specific war file, imagine if i should run many wars( server.xml is not solving

Comment: to solve problems three copies i forgot to specify autoDeploy="false" deployOnStartup="false"