# How to have spring MVC app direct to generic .com url

Tags: java, spring-mvc

So for example, if my project name is WebApp and my domain is www.google.com, when running locally I have to type in www.google.com/WebApp. That's not super easy for clients, so I was wondering if there is a way to direct to a home page when typing in www.google.com? Any tips appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Where are you deploying? To get to `www.google.com` you have to deploy to the root context or point the root to where you deployed.

[Deploying my application at the root in Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328518/deploying-my-application-at-the-root-in-tomcat)

> You have a couple of options:
>
> Remove the out-of-the-box ROOT/ directory from tomcat and rename your
> war file to ROOT.war before deploying it.
>
> Deploy your war as (from
> your example) war_name.war and configure the context root in
> conf/server.xml to use your war file :
>
> The first
> one is easier, but a little more kludgy. The second one is probably
> the more elegant way to do it.

Comment: Good question, I suppose I haven't landed on that yet. Still developing the website, but I was just curious if it's possible before moving forward with this format. I'll check out deploying to the root context thank you. I just don't want to have someone type in the url /projectname, that way it's easier for their customers.