# FAIL - War file cannot be uploaded if context is defined in server.xml (Spring mvc)

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, tomcat7, web-deployment

I'm trying to deploy my webapplication (made with Spring MVC) on the server of a provider (Tomcat 7). I was trying to upload my ROOT.WAR, by using Tomcat manager page (without specifing a context), to the server, but I get this error:

```
FAIL - War file "ROOT.war" cannot be uploaded if context is defined in server.xml
```

How can I solve this problem? I read something on the internet but the solution is not clear to me.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I hope the following link will help you solve this problem.
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328518/deploying-my-application-at-the-root-in-tomcat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328518/deploying-my-application-at-the-root-in-tomcat)

Comment: @aamirlatif link will help you

Comment: Simple: follow the directions implied by the error message and don't define your `ROOT` context in your `server.xml` file.