# How to access War File Build deployed in Tomcat Docker Container after deleting root

Tags: java, ubuntu, tomcat, docker

my docker file:

```
FROM tomcat

MAINTAINER "Shan Khan <xxx@gmail.com">

RUN ["rm", "-rf", "/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT"]

COPY ROOT.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/

CMD ["/usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh", "run"]
```

running as:

```
sudo docker build -t webserver
sudo docker run -it --rm -p 8080:8080 webserver
```

tomcat is running but im unable to access in the localhost:8080 or localhost:8080/ROOT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I was doing this for a work project I seem to remember having to deploy the app to the Tomcat root.

[Deploying my application at the root in Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328518/deploying-my-application-at-the-root-in-tomcat)

So basically you would need to add some steps to your Dockerfile to accomplish this.

Comment: i have tried to add it and put inside the ROOT folder, updated the docker file, but localhost displays now empty page rather than this war file.

Comment: The accepted answer here also rings a bell: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276989/howto-set-the-context-path-of-a-web-application-in-tomcat-7-0. Sorry, it's been a while since I had to do this.

Comment: i have tried it actually, changed the question, and removed the root folder and than running it, same problem

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `CMD ["/usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh", "run"]`, try to do it as `ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh", "run"]`

If this do not resolve your problem, try to see the logs. In the logs you will see something like `deploying webapp ROOT`. If you do not see this logs but you get `server startup took ***ms`, then try to check war file locally or see if there are some errors popping up in `catalina.out` file inside logs folder by connecting to the docker container. (docker ps- command to check the docker container running your dockerfile)