# How to deploy apps in tomcat server

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8

I want to deploy myapp in tomcat server. I know one way is to delete the Root folder from webapps and rename my app.war as ROOT.WAR. But i do not want to do this. I want to deploy like when user access my app as www.xxx.com , it should go to my app like www.xxx.com/login.html.
Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deploying my application at the root in Tomcat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328518/deploying-my-application-at-the-root-in-tomcat)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can deploy any WAR file (or exploded WAR directory) from (almost) anywhere with any context name you want, as long as it doesn't conflict with any auto-deployed application. Here's how:

1. Remove any conflicting applications from `webapps/` (in this case, really, it's just `ROOT`)
2. Move your own application someplace other than in `webapps/`
3. Copy the `META-INF/context.xml` file from your application and place it into Tomcat's `conf/[engine]/[host]/[contextpath].xml` – for example `conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml`
4. Edit `conf/[engine]/[host]/[contextpath].xml` and add this attribute to the `<Context>` element:

   `docBase="/path/to/your/WAR.war"`

Now, Tomcat will deploy `/path/to/your/WAR.war` on context path `/` (because the deployment descriptor's filename is `ROOT`), and you didn't have to modify `conf/server.xml`.

Who cares about modifying `conf/server.xml`? Well, that file is only read *once* during container startup, so if you want to make changes, undeploy, redeploy, etc. you must restart the entire container to pick-up those changes. It's much better to use Tomcat's auto-deployment facility, which as you can see is quite flexible.

All of this is laid out in [Tomcat's documentation on defining contexts](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context) where, incidentally, the very first sentence makes it clear that defining a context in `server.xml` is a bad practice.

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but even after doing this, my app is deployed at `localhost:port/myapp` instead of `localhost:port/`. This is on Tomcat 9.0.20. I am deleting ROOT from webapps, copying `myapp.war` to tomcat/app which is a custom location, copying `myapp.xml` to `/usr/local/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/` which contains `<Context docBase="/usr/local/tomcat/app/myapp.war"></Context>`. Can you help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @SajibAcharya You need to name your XML file `ROOT.xml` instead of `myapp.xml`. Tomcat derives the context path from the name of the XML file, and the name `ROOT.xml` is treated specially by using a zero-length string as the context-path.

Comment: I tried this and after I finish the steps and deploy my war, then 2 new apps show up under Tomcat's Web App Manager list page, one named the original like "myapp" and one "/" for root. However the root app is not started and doesn't work. The "myapp" one works as usual. I tried adjusting the path in ROOT.xml but no luck. Also undeploying deletes the ROOT.xml.  I'll try reading that Tomcat page but may need to go back to just renaming to ROOT.war every time which seems strange but works well.

Comment: If you put your WAR file into Tomcat's auto-deployment `webapps` directory, then it will be deployed twice if you use the method detailed in this answer. Note in step 2 it says *Move your own application someplace other than in `webapps/`*.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz could you elaborate why the solution proposed by you is better than just placing ROOT.war in the `webapps` folder? Using ROOT.war is. by far, much simpler so it would be very helpful to understand why we should favor much more complex solution described above.

Answer (score 2):

You have several options to set a root application. (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5328636/6371459)

1. Remove `ROOT` directory and deploy your war as `ROOT.war`
2. Deploy your war in `webapps` and configure the context root in `conf/server.xml` to use your war file  ([not recommended](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context) because requires restarting)
3. Create a specific context file `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/ROOT.xml`  and set `docBase=your_war_name`  like previous `2)` (see @ChristopherShultz answer)

Since you have discarded option 1, and option 2 is not recommended, I suggest use a context file

Comment: Configuring a `Context` in `server.xml` is a Bad Idea.

Comment: Why @ChristopherSchultz? I could agree but there are not many options if the OP does not want to rename the war to ROOT. If you think this option is not applicable, I think you should include your own answer with the other option of the link instead of marking it as duplicate. 5 of the 6 upvoted answers provide the same tecnhique, and only one negative comment

Answer (score 0):

Configuration file is server.xml

You can just follow this example : https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/tomcat/tomcat-server-xml-configuration-example/

referencing tomcat documentation : http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html