# Why is the website having 2 instances while deploying on apache2 and tomcat7?

Tags: spring, apache, tomcat, deployment

I'm deploying my Java Web Application on VPS which has apache2. The application is being deployed in tomcat7. I've added entries to forward the request from apache to tomcat in httpd.conf. The war file is named as MyWebApplication.war and I've updated the server.xml in tomcat as well.

```
<Context docBase="./MyWebApplication" path="" reloadable="true" />
```

When I'm going to the site, it is both accessible from www.MyWebApplication.com and www.MyWebApplication.com/MyWebApplication.

I want to prevent the access of the application from the second url. What might be the issue here?

Comment: I think you just want to replace the ROOT webapp with MyWebApplication then it will be reached with the / context instead of the /MyWebApplication context. Please read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5328636/7748072).

Comment: I'm already doing the second option. I've named the war as MyWebApplication and updated in the server.xml