# How use Url without artifactid?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, web, artifact

If you put your war in webapps you create a new project. In Url need artifactid/path to file or artifactid/url in Servlet.
How to avoid artifactid? 
And use only url from Servlet.

Comment: In tomcat? There's start from the [root](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5328636/2970947).

Comment: yeah, tomcat 9.0.31