# Spring MVC - run application in absolute path

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, model-view-controller, war

I have a demo application of Spring MVC - I just follow udemy course for it.

I have created the first controller and view. All is working fine, however I have one doubt about.
The pom file of application contains:

```
  <groupId>eu.smartgroup</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-demo-mvc</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
```

So when I run application on tomcat server it starts, but it is available with url: http://localhost:8080/spring_demo_mvc_war

Is there possibility to configure application so it will be available in the root path: http://localhost:8080/ (without project name after slash)?

**Edit:**
Here is full application.yml

```
server:
  servlet:
    contextPath: /
```

HelloController.java

```
package eu.test.springdemo.mvc;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HelloController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String showPage() {
        return "main-menu";
    }
}
```

DemoAppConfig.java

```
package eu.test.springdemo.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages="eu.test.springdemo")
public class DemoAppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    // define a bean for ViewResolver

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {

        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();

        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }
}
```

Comment: Since, you are using Tomcat, I wonder if the base path is defined at the server level. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5328518/9698467

Comment: The preferable approach is to use Spring Boot, which is the modern way of developing applications. If you absolutely can't, you have to install your application as the `ROOT` application in Tomcat.

Comment: Also if you are using a standalone tomcat for your war file, context path you have to configure at server level.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your `application.properties`:

```
server.servlet.contextPath=/
```

I've tried it on my project and it works. 
Write back is it working on your.

Comment: I have application.yml file, so I've added:
```
server:
  servlet:
    contextPath: /
```
but it is not working :(

Comment: Oh sorry you're using Spring without Boot. Wait.

Comment: Code is attached to query

Comment: Okay.. is it possible to run your code without this one dependency in `pom.xml`? May in this dependency is predefined path.

Comment: which dependecy do you mean ?

Comment: Does not matter, at first glance I've thought that first block of code is an dependency. Look ad comment from ` chrylis -cautiouslyoptimistic-` below your question. According to his comment `you have to install your application as the ROOT application in Tomcat`. And if you can, change to Spring Boot. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have a controller class that is annotated as such:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("spring_demo_mvc_war")
```

or

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("spring_demo_mvc_war")
```

If that is the case, then make the string empty or remove the `@RequestMapping` (you can also change it to whatever else you like).

Comment: I have @RequestMapping("/") - like it is presented above