# tomcat generate empty ROOT folder but does not unpack the war file

Tags: java, tomcat, web-deployment

I have gone through some post related to my question but unfortunately I have not managed to get the correct answer.
I have uploaded and rename a war file to `ea-tomcat85/webapps/ROOT.war` in my server. But whenever I restart the tomcat server it only generate an empty ROOT folder without any files inside it. I have try to set `<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">` inside tomcat conf directory file  `server.xml` as suggested in other links with no success. Also I have try to delete and rename the generated empty ROOT folder [as suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5328636/10412027) with no success. I don't know exactly what I am doing wrong or missing. This is my first time deploy a war file into a live server. Thanks in Advance.

**Update**

I have set the `$CATALINA_BASE/bin/setenv.sh:`

```
JRE_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.292.b10-1.el7_9.x86_64/jre
CATALINA_PID="$CATALINA_BASE/tomcat.pid"
```

Just as this [official link](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/RUNNING.txt) illustrate .

But when I start the server as root inside `$CATALINA_HOME/bin/` I get the below output with `JRE_HOME:` missing environment variables.

```
[root@xxxx bin]# ./startup.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/cpanel/ea-tomcat85
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/cpanel/ea-tomcat85
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/cpanel/ea-tomcat85/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /
Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/cpanel/ea-tomcat85/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/cpanel/ea-tomcat85/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started.
```

Comment: Does `ROOT.war` contain any files (its a ZIP archive and you can check it with any archive manager)?

Comment: Are there any errors / messages in `logs/catalina.out`?

Comment: @stdunbar. the error I can see in catalina.out is `org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows using OpenSSL was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]`. Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes @PiotrP.Karwasz . the `ROOT.war` contain some files. Thank in advance

Comment: Stop the server, delete the `webapps/ROOT` folder and check whether Tomcat has permissions to create files in `webapps`. If Tomcat created this folder, there would be a `META-INF/war-tracker` file in it.

Comment: Did this,and it's very strange that the ROOT folder is empty.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz have just updated the question with more details

Comment: Is `CATALINA_BASE` equal to `CATALINA_HOME`? If it is not, you'll need to set the environment variable explicitly before running Tomcat.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz they are not equal. `setenv.sh` for `CATALINA_HOME` is empyt and  in `webapps` under `CATALINA_HOME` there are some default file and folders `docs  examples  host-manager  manager  ROOT`. As you have suggested which files should I use to set their environment variable because `setenv.sh` is not recommended as of this [link](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/RUNNING.txt) for `CATALINA_HOME` and `CATALINA_BASE` variables. And how do I set them. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only environment variable used by `startup.sh` that cannot be set in `setenv.sh` is `CATALINA_BASE` (if it is unset it defaults to `CATALINA_HOME`, which defaults to the parent folder of the `startup.sh` script).

Therefore you need to start you Tomcat as:

```sh
CATALINA_BASE="/path/to/catalina/base" /opt/cpanel/ea-tomcat85/bin/startup.sh
```

The `ROOT` folder in `$CATALINA_BASE/webapps` was empty, since Tomcat used a different value for `CATALINA_BASE`.

Comment: There is only one file `setenv.sh` inside `CATALINA_BASE="/path/to/catalina/base" /opt/cpanel/ea-tomcat85/bin/startup.sh ` unlike `CATALINA_HOME`. How do I configure it? Thank in advance

Comment: The `startup.sh` script sources the first file that is readable between `$CATALINA_BASE/bin/setenv.sh` and `$CATALINA_HOME/bin/setenv.sh`. You just need to create the file in the correct directory (it seems that your settings could apply to any Tomcat instance, so you can put it in `$CATALINA_HOME/bin` and delete the other one).

Comment: Meaning that I should create these files manual in `$CATALINA_BASE/bin/`?

Comment: I thought you already created a `setenv.sh` file in the `$CATALINA_BASE/bin/` folder?

Comment: `setenv.sh` file is there by default, and I have set the environment as shown in the update above. I was asking about the `startup.sh `, `catalina.sh` ,  `shoutdown.sh` all these are not available in ` $CATALINA_BASE/bin/ ` so I cannot start tomcat from there

Comment: Call the ones you have in `$CATALINA_HOME/bin` (`/opt/cpanel/ea-tomcat85/bin` ?), but make sure to set the environment variable `CATALINA_BASE` before either using the one-liner in the answer or by calling `export CATALINA_BASE="..."` before.

Comment: Can you help me on how to set the environment variable on `CATALINA_BASE` as you can see in this [link](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/RUNNING.txt) they haven't explicitly explain about it. Or on how to  `export CATALINA_BASE="..."`  Thanks in advance

Comment: Use the command line I provided in the answer (of course replace `/path/to/catalina/base` with the actual path).