# How to adapt this Angular-SpringBoot-Maven build to a WAR for Tomcat?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, maven, war

There's a very elegant [solution put forth by Marco Molteni](https://marcomolteni.ch/angular-with-java) for building a web-app with an Angular front end and a Spring Boot backend with one Maven build.  Unlike some other solutions, it doesn't depend on third-party Maven plugins, and both halves of the application can be built independently.  They are combined by a third Maven subproject called "delivery" which takes the Java from the backend and the static files from the front end and combines them into one JAR.

The code repo is here: https://github.com/marco76/SpringAngularDemo

However, the output is a standalone JAR.  I need a WAR that can be deployed to a Tomcat container.

The question: **How can I adapt Molteni's design to produce a WAR that can be deployed to Tomcat?**

An ideal answer would preserve the option for JAR output (e.g. if I can use a Maven profile to choose between JAR or WAR, or if *both* can be produced in one build).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `spring-boot-maven-plugin` can create a `jar` or `war` based on the `<packaging>` specified in the POM; if you create a `war`, it can be also used as an executable `jar`: you can deploy it on Tomcat **or** run it from the command line with `java -jar appname.war`.  So the first thing to do is to add

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

in the delivery POM.

The second thing to do is to "hide" the embedded Tomcat: you need it only if you run the app from the command line, so it must be present in the `war` but not in `WEB-INF/lib`.  To get this result you have to declare the embedded Tomcat as "provided": the plugin will put it in `WEB-INF/lib-provided` so it will be ignored by a "regular" Tomcat.

So the POM must be changed as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>dev.marco.demo</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>delivery</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>frontend</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>backend</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        ... (this part has no change)
    </build>
</project>
```

The third thing to do is to modify the main class so that it extends [`SpringBootServletInitializer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/support/SpringBootServletInitializer.html) to initialize Spring Boot when deployed in an application server.

Finally note that the demo application uses Spring Boot 3.x so you need Tomcat 10.1.x; it also assumes that its context-root will be "/", but this is not true, by default, in Tomcat: you can [deploy it in the root context](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5328518/685806) or adapt it further.

Side note: to build the front-end I prefer to use a specific plugin like [`frontend-maven-plugin`](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin) instead of the generic `exec-maven-plugin` because it can also download/install the right version of Node and NPM  if they are not available; they are installed in a project-scoped folder (useful if you have multiple projects with different requirements).  In this way you can just `git clone` the project and `mvn install` even if you are not a front-end developer and you have not the right front-end tools.  This is also useful on a continuous integration server like Jenkins, for example.

Comment: I'll try this today.  It looks like the application launching class needs slightly different setup code for a Tomcat deployment.  I actually want to be able to build both a standalone JAR and a deployable WAR so I'm going to try to create a second app launching class, and have Maven pick the right one for each build.

Comment: I tried this with the original demo, and it doesn't work in Tomcat.  I do not see a `lib-provided` folder under `WEB-INF`. Should this maybe be changed in the 'backend' POM as well as the 'delivery' one?

Comment: My mistake - I didn't notice that build produced TWO `war` files, one original and one "repackaged".  The repackaged one has the `lib-provided` folder.  However, it doesn't work in my Tomcat container.  Could be an issue with Tomcat configuration.

Comment: I have edited my answer and added some other notes.  Follow them and retry.

Comment: Aha, my issue was that I'm using Tomcat 9 so I had to downgrade Spring to version 2.  I forked the original demo code and hosted the solution with README here: https://github.com/joeclark-phd/SpringAngularDemo