# How to deploy a Ldap war file in tomcat? to access site localhost:8080

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a problem. I created a web app and packaged it with "Ldap" name. Then I put it into tomcat webapps directory. When I enter localhost:8080/Ldap in a browser, it works fine. But I want to start this web app when writing localhost:8080. How can I do this in Tomcat. Is there any Tomcat configuration to supply this. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tomcat 6: How to change the ROOT application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/715506/tomcat-6-how-to-change-the-root-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a context.xml file with your webapp, containing a `Context` element with an empty attribute `path`. This is explained in the [tomcat configuration reference](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html).

```
<Context path="" ...>
    ...
</Context>
```

This context.xml file should be located under `/META-INF/` in your web application (not `/WEB-INF/`).