# How to make the application context run as root in Spring 3 MVC and eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, model-view-controller

I’m trying to develop a Spring 3 MVC application using the Springsource Tool Suite/Eclipse IDE.

My current application context in STS/Eclipse is  **/localhost:8080/realtyguide/**

What I want is to access the application as root using just **/localhost:8080/**

I tried in eclipse..  Project > Properties > Web Project Settings > entered “/” for Context  Root .  But this just returned a “404 error - requested resource (/) is not available” after executing the app. And it also broke the app. So I just put context root back to 'realtyguide'.

I deployed  the app to my webhost on a Tomcat server. I edited the server.xml’s  and   elements and so I was able to bring up the index page with the url   www.mydomain.com.

However, the links to the other pages are broken. It is also not picking up the static resources for the index page like css and jquery files.

I believe this is caused by my app’s application context of /localhost:8080/realtyguide/ in eclipse (in my development pc).  The rest of the pages returned by my controller has a url of **/localhost:8080/realtyguide/page_name**

How do I change my app’s application context to **run as root in eclipse**,  as in simply **/localhost:8080/**. So that my pages would be called as simply **/localhost:8080/page_name**

Is the solution a setting I should make in my web or  Spring configuration files or in eclipse?

I’ve tried googling this but have not found a clear, definitve answer. I am very new to this and a detailed answer from you will be of great help.

Comment: You may want to try the `root` context path with your app bundled as root.war as mentioned [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/424290/Tomcat/deploy-Root-Tomcat-Website)

Comment: Another related SO entry http://stackoverflow.com/q/715506/862441

Comment: I’m not sure if I wrote my question correctly. 
I was already able to deploy the app as root  in tomcat and access the index page thru /www.mydomain.com/ 

My problem is that it is broken. It doesn’t pick up my css and js files and the page links are broken.

I edited my post. Please see my edited post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the other answers provided. However, it doesn't address my main objective - to run the app as root inside eclipse.

This is how I was able to do it. I changed Tomcat's conyext path in eclipse.

Do the following:

1. Right click on the server name from the `Server Console  >  Open`
2. Click on the `Modules` tab
3. Click on a module then click the `Edit` button
4. Edit the entry for `Path` to the desired context path then click
   `OK`

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your web-app the "default" application, `ROOT`. There are step-by-step instructions on the Tomcat Wiki, at http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo#How_do_I_make_my_web_application_be_the_Tomcat_default_application.3F.

Comment: I’m not sure if I wrote my question correctly. 
I was already able to deploy the app as root  in tomcat and access the index page thru /www.mydomain.com/ 

My problem is that it is broken. It doesn’t pick up my css and js files and the page links are broken.

I edited my post. Please see my edited post.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to name the war simply `ROOT.war` (uppercase). 
*This works only if you deploy not from eclipse*

If you have done your links/urls with `<c:url>` or `<spring:url>` then it should work without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change server.xml in Tomcat Server.

1. `Package Explorer > Servers`
2. expend path `Tomcat vX.X Server`
3. open `server.xml`
4. go to `Server > Service > Engine`
5. find your `Context` and change `path` to value "/"
6. restart the server!