# Getting context of another webapp in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, tomcat8, cross-context

I have the following configuration running on Tomcat 8.0.20:

```
C:\tomcat
   conf
     server.xml
     context.xml
   webapps
     app
     app2
   ......
C:\external
     app3
        web
     app4
        web
     app5
        web
```

In context.xml I have `<Context crossContext="true"> .... </Context>`

And in server.xml:

```
 ..........
 <Host name="host.com"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
    <Context 
      cachingAllowed="false"
      docBase="C:\external\app3\web" 
      path="" 
      crossContext="true"
      reloadable="true" />

    <Context 
      cachingAllowed="false"
      crossContext="true"
      docBase="C:\external\app4\web" 
      path="/app4"
      reloadable="true" />

    <Context 
      cachingAllowed="false"
      crossContext="true"
      docBase="C:\external\app5\web" 
      path="/app5"
      reloadable="true" />
 </Host>
```

Obtaining the Context of `/app`, `/app2` or `/app5` from `/app4` works as espected:

`request.getServletContext().getContext("/app")` is not null.

However, requesting the Context of `/app3` (with context path `/`).

Any idea why `getContext("/")` is null?

Comment: Here's an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001623/forwarding-requests-between-contexts-in-tomcat)... you need to set the root path.

Comment: Just changed `/app3` to `/` which is now the root path. Still doesn't work for apps outside `webapps`. Any ideas?

Comment: Just a hunch... try using path relative mapping instead of 'windows' dir mapping... I.E. `/external/app3/web`, `/external/app4/web`

Comment: Doesn't work either. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turned out, it's a regression in tomcat after version 8.0.15

Filed a bug report [here](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57733)

Reverted tomcat to 8.0.15 and it's working now....