# how do I map my domain name to an application in TOMCAT server installed in my System which has static IP?

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat7, web-hosting

I am planning to host JSP based private server. I have static IP with me and I have redirected the name server in domain manager account to that IP. And I want to know how to map www.domainname.com to a particular application in tomcat server ?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you'll want to replace the root web application of your Tomcat, there's a fairly lengthy thread about that subject [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715506/tomcat-6-how-to-change-the-root-application) discussing the different ways to do that, and also how to avoid losing Tomcat Manager in the process.