# Set root application of domain on host server

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, tomcat6

I am struggling badly to set my application as the default. It's running on a private jvm hosted by a hosting company  I've tried renaming it to ROOT and it becomes accessible by mydomain/index.html. So now I need to make it accessible without the `index.html`.

The most important thing to note is that this app is not deployed in tomcat/webapps/. It is deployed in tomcat/domain/mydomain/. That is the way my host has it set up and maps the directories to their given domains in the conf/server.xml file.

I've tried several approaches and no luck, also the hosts support has give me the run around since Monday, at one point breaking my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the `<welcome-file-list>` tag which can be used in your `web.xml`. A good explanation of this can be found here: http://wiki.metawerx.net/wiki/Web.xml.WelcomeFileList

Answer (score 0):

you need to add ROOT.xml file in conf/Catalina/localhost directory to Set root application of domain.Please refer to this link for more info. [Tomcat 6: How to change the ROOT application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715506/tomcat-6-how-to-change-the-root-application)