# Apache Server is showing default page on browser

Tags: tomcat, servlets, web

I've created one java website which is hosted on Apache Tomcat server 7.0.37.
I've also purchased a domain name called www.parsits.info but when I use the link in browser, it opens up apache default page instead of my home page. but when opened with www.parsits.info/ITS/ it shows my welcome page.

how do I make my welcome to appear when address www.parsits.info is entered in browser?

Comment: Check this question out, it talks about changing the root webpage in the tomcat configuration: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/715506/tomcat-6-how-to-change-the-root-application

Comment: how are you redirecting from Apache to Tomcat?