# How to Access my tomcat application using just server URL

Tags: tomcat

I am running a web-app on tomcat server and I am able to access the application normally using <"https://serverurl.com/app_name>"

I want to cut this URL short and access my application via https://serverurl.com

What would be the easiet way to acheive this

Answer (score 0):

As I see it you have two options

1. Deploy your application to [ROOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715506/tomcat-6-how-to-change-the-root-application) context
2. Place a redirection index page in the existing ROOT context to redirect to your webapp. Or use URL rewriting if using front-end webserver.