# Open application by entering just ip address

Tags: java, tomcat, configuration, tomcat7, web.xml

I have an application deployed in Tomcat 7.
Now there is one application called studentManagement

Till now I open application by entering the http://{IPAddress}/studentManagement

Now, I want to open that application by just entering the IPAddress only.

Comment: You are basically trying to set the root application to run in tomcat to your application... you can do that by following a previous post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/715506/tomcat-6-how-to-change-the-root-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot rename the application, you can add the following to Server/Service/Engine/Host in TOMCAT_HOME/conf/server.xml

```
<Context path="" docBase="NAME-OF-DIRECTORY-UNDER-WEBAPPS">
  <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
</Context>
```

Comment: Thnx thiw worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Replace your application as the ROOT.war so it by default loads when only the IP address is loaded.  Consider the fact that also when you deploy it, later if you want to apply a patch to without restarting you can just ROOT##0001.war.

There are a number of solutions you can follow [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715506/tomcat-6-how-to-change-the-root-application)

Comment: I can not change to ROOT.war, please suggest some other configuration based solution.