# Change the root context to other folder in tomcat 6

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6

I want to change the context of my deployed web application. Currently it is accessed by the url `www.app.mysite.com/dashboard`

But i want to change it to `www.app.mysite.com/application/dashboard`

I went through post to change the root context [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276989/howto-set-the-context-path-of-a-web-application-in-tomcat-7-0) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715506/tomcat-6-how-to-change-the-root-application). But the thing is that i have other applications running to on that server which are accessed by

```
www.app.mysite.com/ps
www.app.mysite.com/ls
```

If i change the context path in server.xml will it affect context of my other application ?I dont want the context to change for above mentioned apps, but i want to change it for my particular application dashboard.

Is there any way to change the context of any particular application, by adding any thing to web.xml or other?

Comment: I assume you can have two <Context> elements, each with its own path and its own docBase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a way to do it (step-by-step):

1. Put your expanded WAR in a directory **outside of webapps**. My TOMCAT_HOME is `/home/nikos/apache-tomcat-6.0.37` and I placed my app in the folder `myapp` under a new folder: `$TOMCAT_HOME/webapps-manual`. I.e. the folder structure is:

   ```
   $TOMCAT_HOME
   |
   +- ...
   |
   +- webapps (NOT HERE!!!)
   |
   +- webapps-manual
      |
      +- myapp
         |
         +- index.jsp
         |
         +- WEB-INF
            |
            +- web.xml (optional)
   ```
2. Edit TOMCAT_ROOT/conf/server.xml. Add the following `<Context>` under the appropriate `<Host>` element (there is probably only one):

   ```
   <Host ...>
       <Context
           path="/application/dashboard"
           docBase="/home/nikos/apache-tomcat-6.0.37/webapps-manual/myapp"
       />
   </Host>
   ```
3. DONE! Open `http://localhost:8080/application/dashboard/index.jsp` and see content generated by `$TOMCAT_HOME/webapps-manual/myapp/index.jsp`.

See relevant documentation [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html) (see attributes `path` and `docBase`).

Answer (score 0):

I doubt whether this is possible in tomcat. Best would be to use apache http server or else, create two applications one with context root application (dummy application) with a servlet to route all the request to dashboard.

Let me know if you are able to do this in tomcat in a better way