# Deploying webapp on Tomcat7

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, jetty

My problem is that I'm trying to deploy my spring-based webapp on Tomcat. Out of being used to that I embedded jetty for tests, and it worked fine. Whole app is responding correctly when I stop tomcat and just run it. Problem begins when I try to deploy it on Tomcat (it needs to be deployed that way, becouse that is how it will be deployed in production).

My Main.class:

```
package pl.tracer.config;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.ResourceCollection;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext;

public class Main {

private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName());

public static void main(final String[] aArgs) throws Exception {

    logger.log(Level.INFO, "Starting");
    final Server server = new Server(8080);
    server.setHandler(createWebAppContext());

    server.start();
    server.join();
}

private static WebAppContext createWebAppContext() {
    final WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
    context.setContextPath("/");
    context.setBaseResource(new ResourceCollection(
            new String[] { "./src/main/java/META-INF/webapp" }));
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "Created context");
    return context;
}
}
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

<display-name>RunTracer</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>tracer</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>tracer</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

tracer-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="pl.tracer" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
</beans>
```

The only (simple) controller:

```
package pl.tracer.requestHandling;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import pl.tracer.entities.Track;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public class TrackController {

@Autowired
private TrackService service;

@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Map<Long, List<Track>> getAll(
        @RequestParam(required = true) List<Long> ids,
        @RequestParam(required = false) Integer count) {
    Map<Long, List<Track>> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (Long id : ids) {
        List<Track> tracks = service.getAll(id, count);
        map.put(id, tracks);
    }
    return map;
}
}
```

And pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<groupId>tracer-server</groupId>
<artifactId>tracer-server</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<name>TracerServer</name>

<properties>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <spring-framework.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>

    <!-- Baza danych -->
    <hibernate-entitymanager.version>4.2.6.Final</hibernate-entitymanager.version>
    <hibernate-validator.version>4.3.1.Final</hibernate-validator.version>
    <spring-data-jpa.version>1.4.1.RELEASE</spring-data-jpa.version>
    <mysql.version>5.1.6</mysql.version>

    <!-- Jetty -->
    <jetty.version>9.1.0.RC2</jetty.version>

    <!-- Jackson -->
    <jackson.version>2.3.0</jackson.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jetty -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-servlets</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jackson, mapper potrzebny by można było mapować jsona na obiekty -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-entitymanager.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate validation -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-validator.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring and Transactions -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring jdbc/orm/data jpa, wszystko potrzebne do poprawnej komunikacji 
        springa z bazą -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-data-jpa.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}</webappDirectory>
                <warName>tracer</warName>
                <archive>
                    <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>false</addClasspath>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries />
                    <manifestFile />
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
</build>
```

As You can see, it's as simple as can be.
I also attach logs from tomcat:

```
cze 29, 2014 10:51:12 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
cze 29, 2014 10:51:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 593 ms
cze 29, 2014 10:51:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
cze 29, 2014 10:51:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.26
cze 29, 2014 10:51:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/host-    manager.xml
cze 29, 2014 10:51:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/manager.xml
cze 29, 2014 10:51:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/tracer.war
cze 29, 2014 10:51:13 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/tracer/WEB-INF/lib/javax.servlet-    3.0.0.v201112011016.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending     class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
cze 29, 2014 10:51:13 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/tracer/WEB-INF/lib/javax.servlet-api-    3.1.0.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class:     javax/servlet/Servlet.class
cze 29, 2014 10:51:13 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/tracer/WEB-INF/lib/jsp-api-2.1-glassfish-    2.1.v20100127.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class:     javax/el/Expression.class
cze 29, 2014 10:51:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://www.springframework.org/tags is already defined
cze 29, 2014 10:51:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://www.springframework.org/tags/form is already defined
cze 29, 2014 10:51:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt is already defined
cze 29, 2014 10:51:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core is already defined
cze 29, 2014 10:51:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core is already defined
cze 29, 2014 10:51:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt_rt is already defined
cze 29, 2014 10:51:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt is already defined
cze 29, 2014 10:51:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt is already defined
cze 29, 2014 10:51:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions is already defined
cze 29, 2014 10:51:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/permittedTaglibs is     already defined
cze 29, 2014 10:51:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/scriptfree is already     defined
cze 29, 2014 10:51:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql_rt is already defined
cze 29, 2014 10:51:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql is already defined
cze 29, 2014 10:51:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql is already defined
cze 29, 2014 10:51:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml_rt is already defined
cze 29, 2014 10:51:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml is already defined
cze 29, 2014 10:51:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml is already defined
cze 29, 2014 10:51:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT
cze 29, 2014 10:51:17 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
cze 29, 2014 10:51:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 5128 ms
```

Can someone help me, and say why this app doesn't let me perform simple GET on

```
"http://localhost:8080/tracer?ids=1"
```

? I always receive 404 error.

Just to assure, that deploying webapps with embedded jetty on tomcat is possible- I have tried this few times and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embedded jetty has no connection to this. That main class that you have which starts the jetty up is just passive and won't be invoked when deploying this as a webapp in tomcat.

This line caught my eye

```
    new String[] { "./src/main/java/META-INF/webapp" }));
```

Looks like your webroot is not the usual place. I guess in that case you should tell tomcat about that using docBase. You can see that in the manual or in places like [Change the root context to other folder in tomcat 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18873063/change-the-root-context-to-other-folder-in-tomcat-6)

Also there are some jar conflicts (basically servlet-api etc). Did you check if the application was started properly - either in tomcat logs or the manager app? I see you've started that. I guess the url goes something like `http://localhost:8080/manager` or so

Comment: You are right. All that was needed to be done was to move my webapp folder from src/main/java/META-INF/ to src/main/. Thanks a lot :)