# Tomcat context path change for accessing the app from root

Tags: java, tomcat, war, tomcat5.5, contextpath

We have tomcat 5.5.25. There are around 10 war files deployed in this tomcat.

All the war files are in a separate directory, and we have xml files for each app in conf/catalina/localhost folder.

For example take app.war application

`app.war` file is present in a /tomcat/apps directory.

`app.xml` file present in conf/catalina/localhost folder.

and exploded directory is present in webapps folder.

`app.xml` file looks like this

```
<Context path="/app"docBase="/tomcat/apps/app.war">
</Context>
```

and this application is accessible using url

> `http://mytomcat:8080/app`

Now My requirement is to access the application directly using the url

> `http://mytomcat:8080/`

To achieve this what configurations do I need to change? please help

Comment: Have you tried to use the "ROOT" folder as your webapp folder or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/715506/tomcat-6-how-to-change-the-root-application to convert your app.war in the ROOT app

Answer (score 2):

Rename `app.xml` to `ROOT.xml` in the `conf/catalina/localhost` folder and change the file into:

```
<Context
  path=""
  docBase="/tomcat/apps/app.war">
</Context>
```

Answer (score 0):

Context path must be mapped to `"/"`. convention is to call the web app at the root folder `ROOT`, and Tomcat will deploy a web app of that name to root if you let Tomcat auto-deploy.