# Tomcat Server and Domain Mapping?

Tags: tomcat, dns

I map Domian name with Tomcat server

```
<Host name="www.abc.in" appBase="webapps"
       unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
       xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
                         <Context reloadble="true" path="/3c" docBase="3c" >
 <Alias>abc.in</Alias>
 <Alias>www.abc.in</Alias>

</Host>
```

But when i am doing `http://abc.in` is it showing **Apache Tomcat** home page so if i want to access project i have to give this url `http://abc.in/3c`

What changes i have to do project home page when someone access `http://abc.in` or `http://www.abc.in`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i Have done this with the help of

> First shutdown your Tomcat from the its bin directory (sh
>   shutdown.sh). Then delete all the content of your Tomcat webapps
>   folder (rm -fr *). Then rename your WAR file to ROOT.war, and finally
>   start your Tomcat from the bin directory (sh startup.sh).

Help was taken from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715506/tomcat-6-how-to-change-the-root-application) in **Stackoverflow**