# java web project remove folders from the url

Tags: java, tomcat, web, war

I have a java web project myapp running on tomcat 8
my html file is in myapp/app/index.html 
But i dont want the app to be seen in the url - just myapp/index.html 
How can this be done

Answer (score 0):

You can use the rewrite Valve.

```
myapp/
  app/index.html
  META-INF/context.xml <-- add
  WEB_INF/
    rewrite.config <-- add
    web.xml
```

context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Context>
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve"/>
</Context>
```

rewrite.config:

```
RewriteRule ^/index.html /app/index.html
RewriteRule ^/$ /app/index.html
```

Comment: Where and how do i add it ?

Comment: I created a minimal webapp that works. Note that you should remove `index.jsp` from your app root.

Comment: it doesnt seems to work nothing happens when i go to http://localhost:8080/app/index.html

Comment: Well...you should access localhost:8080/myapp/index.html

Comment: It doesnt seems to handle the request

Answer (score 0):

Or you could run your app in the root context of tomcat:

- [Deploying my application at the root in Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328518/deploying-my-application-at-the-root-in-tomcat)
- [How to set the context path of a web application in Tomcat 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276989/howto-set-the-context-path-of-a-web-application-in-tomcat-7-0)
- [Tomcat 6: How to change the ROOT application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715506/tomcat-6-how-to-change-the-root-application)

Comment: Thomas Steinbach I will still see the subdirectory in  the url path

Comment: The obvious solution to that problem, to copy the web resources to the webapp root folder, is not acceptable I guess? Why are they in an 'app' subfolder? To maintain an easier to manage hierarchy for development perhaps?

Comment: Yes exactly  that's the idea