# How to deploy a java application as root in tomcat without allow access to other webapps

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, deployment, root

I have a java application.war and I copied the file to tomcat7/webapps directory.

I'm able to access it with www.application.com/application (My domain points to ip 200.xyz.12.jk:8080) BUT

I want to access it through www.application.com  (without the name of the folder inside webapps directory)

Also i dont want to allow access to other folders inside webapps.

I have tried some topics but didnt succeed.

Failed to help:
[Deploying my application at the root in Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328518/deploying-my-application-at-the-root-in-tomcat)

https://josefbetancourt.wordpress.com/2011/02/12/tomcat7-change-root-app/

[Tomcat 6: How to change the ROOT application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715506/tomcat-6-how-to-change-the-root-application)

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your tomcat under apache http server then point it to tomcat's AJP protocol.

**Example of Apache httpd.conf configuration:**

```
Listen 80
ProxyPass / ajp://application.com:8009/application
```

**In tomcat server.xml file you should have below ajp connector:**

```
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" />
```

As a result www.application.com/ url points to the application entire directory over ajp protocol.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: It throws "ProxyPass|ProxyPassMatch needs a path when not defined in a location" with config you said

Comment: That's ok. Use virtual host instead: <VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPass ajp://application.com:8009/application </VirtualHost>. See more info here - https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#virtualhost