# Auto-redirect root path to Spring Boot Context Path

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot Context Path as specified in the application.properties file, and it works great

```
server.port=5000
server.context-path=/services
```

Spring Boot 2.0 and above

```
server.port=5000
server.servlet.context-path=/services
```

But how can we achieve default redirect of root i.e. “/” to “/services”

http://localhost:5000/services - works great!

But I want http://localhost:5000/ to automatically redirect to -> http://localhost:5000/services so that an end user should be able to access the root of the domain and be automatically redirected to the context path

Currently accessing the root is throwing a 404 (which makes sense with the default configuration)

How can I achieve the automatic redirect of root i.e. “/”  to the context path?

Comment: But why would you do that. Simply remove context if you want to open it directly.

Comment: We want to use context for all the other endpoints, but just need the root to auto-redirect

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think I can provide a solution.Please refer to the following code.

```
@Configuration
public class RootServletConfig {

    @Bean
    public TomcatServletWebServerFactory servletWebServerFactory() {
        return new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {

            @Override
            protected void prepareContext(Host host, ServletContextInitializer[] initializers) {
                super.prepareContext(host, initializers);
                StandardContext child = new StandardContext();
                child.addLifecycleListener(new Tomcat.FixContextListener());
                child.setPath("");
                ServletContainerInitializer initializer = getServletContextInitializer(getContextPath());
                child.addServletContainerInitializer(initializer, Collections.emptySet());
                child.setCrossContext(true);
                host.addChild(child);
            }
        };
    }

    private ServletContainerInitializer getServletContextInitializer(String contextPath) {
        return (c, context) -> {
            Servlet servlet = new HttpServlet() {
                @Override
                protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
                    resp.sendRedirect(contextPath);
                }
            };
            context.addServlet("root", servlet).addMapping("/*");
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly for me. This solution adds a root servlet that redirects, similar what was suggested for the classic Tomcat: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30490642/tomcat-redirect-old-context-root-to-new-context-root

Comment: how to do this with undertow instead of embedded tomcat

Comment: Brilliant answer! I had a problem with this: if a Chrome user requests /contextPath/mypage, after successful login by username/password form, they got redirected to the /contextPath, not /contextPath/mypage.  The problem is that Spring Security saves the last unauthenticated request and redirects to that upon success.  When they got redirected to the login form, this was /contextPath/mypage.  Then Chrome requested "/favicon.ico", which got redirected to /contextPath by the code above and this replaced the last saved request.  I fixed this with `sendRedirect(contextPath + req.getRequestURI())`.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you cannot do this simply. Setting `server.servlet.context-path=/services` sets your server's root path to `/services`. And when you redirect a path with `/` - in fact, you are redirecting with a path `/services`.
Here's what I tried to solve this problem:

- If you have an intermediate web server in front of your application (*apache, nginx*) - you can do a redirect in its settings.
- Or you can replace the `server.servlet.context-path` setting with your own pathname something like this:
  `app.endpoints.services_path=/services` in `application.config`
  `@RequestMapping("${app.endpoints.services_path}")` mapping in *Controller*.
  And after that make a redirect from the path `/` to `/services`.

For example, in one of these ways:

- With a redirect controller

```
@Controller
public class RootRedirectController {
    @GetMapping(value = "/")
    public void redirectToServices(HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse){
        httpServletResponse.setHeader("Location", "/services");
        httpServletResponse.setStatus(302);
    }
}
```

- Or by adding customization to *Spring Boot*

```
@Configuration
public class WebAppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("forward:/services");
        // This method can be blocked by the browser!
        // registry.addRedirectViewController("/", "redirect:/services");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps. Sorry my Google Translate.