# How to point ip address to webapp

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, webserver, ip-address

I'm new to deploying applications on a live server so please bear with me

I have a static IP address and a webapp deployed on a server pointed at by said IP address.

So right now I can access the webapp from any machine like so

`12.123.123.123:8080/myapp`

How do I configure Tomcat so that I don't have to specify the port and the app name? Any pointer would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

`http://12.123.123.123/` is just shorthand for `http://12.123.123.123:80/`, so you will want to set up Tomcat to run on port 80 (or port 443 if you're doing HTTPS). Next, you want to deploy to `/` instead of `/myapp` - in Tomcat, this means using the special "ROOT" app-name for your app (it can be ROOT.war for example) - the all-caps is important.

Comment: You can see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6093662/2506382) for several ways to deploy to "ROOT".

Comment: I get permission denied for port 80, I wonder how I could get around this

Comment: I just had to set authBind=yes