# Tomcat 404 error, image js and css are not found

Tags: javascript, java, css, image, tomcat

I used tomcat 7 for deploy my war file. It contains various images, css and js file.

I configure my tomcat on port 8080. Everything goes fine but I don't know why these content not serve by tomcat. It gives 404 not found error.

**Directory Structure**

[image: My Directory Structure]

And I hit this below url

```
http://localhost:8080/images/jackson2.png
```

When I put these images outside ROOT folder to inside webapps/examples/ then it works fine.

Now what is wrong with it ? It there anything I missed ?
I could not understand the issue ? Help me

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/715506/tomcat-6-how-to-change-the-root-application

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps check that tomcat and/or the image files have the correct permissions set, I'm not too sure how to go about it on windows, depending on which version your running it could be a UAC issue, you can try looking here: https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-windows. You can try stopping tomcat, remove the work and temp directories, then starting tomcat.

Comment: Also, make sure you've got the right file extension there in the url.

Comment: file extension is right because if I copy these images and put in the webapps/examples/images/jackson2.png then it works

Comment: Okay, and your able to access other resources under the ROOT directory?

Comment: No, under ROOT directory I can only access html pages and jsp pages

Comment: Okay, try adding a WEB-INF/web.xml file, something like <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd"> <web-app> </web-app>